# Scrollable grid

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I have been struggling with making a grid scrollable in my wpf application and the scrollviewer is not working so I need something similar to overflow:scroll in CSS so if anybody could help I would be very grateful

```
<Grid Margin="12,49,0,54" Name="state_settings" Width="430" Visibility="Hidden" MaxHeight="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid Height="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,10,0,0" Name="state_comp" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="406">
            <Label Content="Gesture" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,31,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,31,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" />
            <Label Content="Min Duration" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,6,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,31,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,31,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
            <Label Content="Max Duration" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,6,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Transition" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,6,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am damm sure you have made a mistake otherwise Scrollviewer working fine in WPF

Comment: you need to set `Height` for `ScrollViewer`, and remove `Height` setting from your inner `Grid`.

Comment: I don't have a machine available to test, but try setting `CanContentScroll` to `False`. If memory serves, you're currently telling it that "the `Grid` can scroll, so don't worry."

Comment: I need the outer grid to be scrollable not the inner one

Comment: then you need to put `ScrollViewer` outside the outer grid.

Comment: I placed the scrollviewer outside the outer grid and it is still not working

Comment: The thing is I am dynamically appending in the outer grid a copy of the inner grid again so the outer grid needs to have a vertical scrollbar to allow for such new components

Comment: Delete all this horrible thing and use a proper `ItemsControl`. Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change a few things to make it easier to work with your code... for example, I had to remove the `Visibility="Hidden"`, which was ridiculous of you to keep in your example. I also added a `Background` colour so that I could see the bounds of the `Grid`. I moved the `ScrollViewer` to be the outermost element and removed the unnecessary `CanContentScroll` property and some `Height` settings, but apart from that, you almost had it. Try this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Name="state_settings" Width="430" MaxHeight="200" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid Height="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,10,0,0" Name="state_comp" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="406">
            <Label Content="Gesture" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,31,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,31,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" />
            <Label Content="Min Duration" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,6,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,31,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,31,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
            <Label Content="Max Duration" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,6,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Transition" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,6,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You *may* need to reduce the `Height` of your `Window`, or add more items in order to actually see the vertical `ScrollBar`, but if you do, you should now see that it scrolls.

Your UI *with* a `ScrollBar`:
[image]

Comment: Firstly, you're quite welcome to the time that I spent helping you. Secondly, if you copy and paste this example into a new project, you'll see that actually, it *does* work. As I said, you *may* need to reduce the `Height` of your `Window`, or add more items in order to actually see the vertical `ScrollBar`, but if you do, you *will* now see that it scrolls. I've also just tested it on both .NET 4 and 4.5 and in Visual Studio 2010 *and* 2013, so I *know* that it works.